# Waiting because no window has focus but there is a "focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up

Tags: android

Please help me to understand what is meaning of below ANR?
"Waiting because no window has focus but there is a  "focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up."

Comment: Can you give us some context of what you were doing at the time?  My guess would be that you have the UI thread pausing too long and tripping a watchdog, but that's a pure guess.

Comment: I have an background transparent activity (No UI), which will launch while device receive incoming phone call intent (android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE). Issues is when I press volume key continuously it  throw  ANR . I am not overriding onkeyEvent and dispatchKeyEvent.

Comment: Sounds like ANdroid is trying to dispatch the key, and it sees that your app has the priority, but that you don't have a UI to dispatch it to.  And then its waiting for you to put a UI up.  Since you don't, it can't process the key and ends up ANRing your app.  WHy do you have a transparent UI-  if you don't have any UI elements you should be in a service or BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Yeh, I have used service for that and there is no ANR . But I have some design issue and it is already implemented code running  in production. I just want to know is there any solution to avoid ANR with activity without UI component.

Answer (score 4):

I think this happens when an activity is started but somehow it doesn't add any content view to interact with user. I also saw this error on developer console because there was an issue with app's framework and it used to get stuck on splash screen. The reason was the activity doesn't call setContentView by default but waits for the app framework to initialize, and when framework initialized completely it didn't add any view to activity because of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am facing the same issue and this is what I come up with.

The log you mentioned:
"Waiting because no window has focus but there is a "focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up."

is dispatched by the InputDispatcher.cpp from AOSP framework.

It happens when InputDispatcher is waiting for application to add a window to inject input. If the time waiting > 5000ms, then you will have an ANR.

Comment: You got solution to this issue? @banana-droid

Comment: @Shanmugapriyan, it depends on different cases. For me, it was one of my apps are memory leaked. I meant this issue is not specifically point out the problem underneath.